# Include external JS/CSS libraries in a module?

Tags: 8

What is the Drupal 8 equivalent of including external libraries (like sites/all/libraries) for custom modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [this blog post](http://www.agoradesign.at/blog/3rd-party-library-integration-drupal-8)

> **Core API changes in Drupal 8**
>
> The drupal_add_js() and drupal_add_css() functions for manual inclusions of JS/CSS files have been removed in favour of library definitions that properly declare their dependencies. As a result of this, all modules and also themes have to declare their libraries in order to include JS and/or CSS files. During the development of D8 the way of declaring a library evolved from a renamed info hook (hook_library_info()) to finally using YAML (like in many other places in D8) [by describing the libraries in *.libraries.yml files](https://www.drupal.org/node/1996238). The info hook finally was removed fully. [See the change record for more information](https://www.drupal.org/node/2201089). The new hook_library_info_alter() hook is of course still there.
>
> Another big change is the usage of Composer for dependency management, like many other modern frameworks do. Although Composer is primarily for PHP libraries, it can be used for JS libraries too. Using Composer not only spares you manually downloading the library from Github, etc and afterwards manually extracting and uploading the files to your server, but also eliminates the error source of placing the files into the right directory structure. (Note: Composer integration is not fully finished yet, see: [https://www.drupal.org/node/2372815)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2372815)

Comment: How would I ask someone to edit their composer in the root directory? Also, I thought it was considered bad form to define libraries external to the module within the module's libraries.yml. I guess I am wondering, is it now acceptable to put in the readme to download the needed libraries into css/js or vendor/ folder of the module?

Answer (score 1):

The module.libraries.yml file is a great improvement in Drupal 8. You can define  css and js files you need for one task in your module, so that other modules can use them.

But it is not supposed to make the libraries module completly redundant. For external libraries, that are not specific to one module, it may still be advisable to use the shared library folder:

[Libraries API 8.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704734)

To answer the question, the equivalant in drupal 8 is the same as in drupal 7. But we have to see, how the module developers will use the new possibilities, and how much will be left for the shared libraries.

**Edit:**

A lot of people get confused by the name of this 2 hooks:

1. hook_library_info()
2. hook_libraries_info()

The first one is in core of drupal 7 and got replaced by the new libraries system in drupal 8. The second one is from the contrib module [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) and is still alive.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if Libraries was still around, but I thought for sure they kept saying that that module was no longer needed in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you wanted the library served via a CDN, but for a lot of people that might be the case. Here's an example with Fontawesome (webfont icon library).

This is from a theme, but the principle is exactly the same with a module.

*mytheme.libraries.yml*:

```
[...]

fontawesome:
  js:
    "//kit.fontawesome.com/1abc23d4ef.js": { type: external }
```

*mytheme.info.yml*:

```
[...]

libraries:
  - mytheme/fontawesome
```

(Then clear the cache.)

If you're including CSS you need to specify it's [SMACSS](http://smacss.com) category (base, component, theme etc.) which controls the order it's loaded in.

Note I'm not *actually* sure what `type: external` does (it still works without). If someone can clarify I'll edit the answer.

Further reading:

- [Define an asset library](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/define-asset-library?p=2512) (Drupalize.me - paywall)
- [Attach a library](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/attach-library?p=2512) (Drupalize.me - paywall)